# Solving the following Integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following Integral equation:
$$
y''+\int_{0}^{x}q\cdot(y^2)\:\mathrm{d}y-2=0
$$
With consideration that $q$ is very small and ignore powers of $q$ which are bigger than $1$.

(I mean write the functions in the Integral equation as the functions of the $q$)

Expansion and approximation may be necessary.

Comment: This is in need of a convincing definition of the integral term, if it is not meant to be $\frac13q\cdot(y^3(x)-y^3(0))$.

Comment: This will help: [Perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory).